# How many bits in a byte (Arbitrary System)

Tags: c++

In an Arbitrary system where 8bits != 1byte how to find number of bits = byte using programming?

What I have though of is keep on left shifting 1 till I get some wrong value. But how to code it?

Comment: <limits.h> defines the macro constant `CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `CHAR_BIT` macro defined in the [`<climits>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits).  It's a compile-time constant, so you don't have to do anything to figure it out at runtime.

Comment: Is there a way without using CHAR_BIT? I mean using programming?

Comment: Querying `CHAR_BIT` *is* using programming. Exactly what restrictions are you operating under? (I'm guessing this is a homework assignment; if so, I'm hesitant to offer too much help.)

Comment: You could do it using bit-shifting, as you suggested in the question.  But why would you want to write code to figure out at runtime something that's known at compile time?  It's more work for you *and* less efficient for your program.

Comment: Its an interview question. So I thought someone in stackoverflow could help

Comment: Well, you had the right idea already:  initialize a `char` to 1, then left-shift it repeatedly until its value becomes 0 (because the bit was shifted off the end), and count how many shifts it took.

Comment: @Wyzard: That's not reliable. The signedness of plain `char` is implementation-defined, and if it's signed an arithmetic overflow has undefined behavior. Start with an `unsigned char` with the value `-1`, and right-shift it until it reaches zero.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a template metaprogram for a compile-time determination of bit counts of primitive integer types.

This method relies on using an unsigned type because it simplifies things.  This code finds the bit count of an unsigned char.

After determining the bit count of unsigned char, we can use the sizeof opeator to determine the bit count of any type under this "Arbitrary System."

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned char V=~unsigned char(0), int C=0>
struct bit_counter {
    static const int count = 
        bit_counter<(V>>1),C+1>::count;
};
template <int C>
struct bit_counter<0, C> {
    static const int count = C;
};

// use sizeof operator, along with the result from bit_counter
// to get bit count of arbitrary types.
// sizeof(unsigned char) always gives 1 with standard C++, 
// but we check it here because this is some kind of 
// "Arbitrary" version of the language.
template <typename T>
struct bit_count_of {
    static const int value = 
        sizeof(T) * bit_counter<>::count / sizeof(unsigned char);
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "uchar  " << bit_counter<>::count << std::endl;
    std::cout << "long   " << bit_count_of<long>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "double " << bit_count_of<double>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "void*  " << bit_count_of<void*>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can count if you want:

```
int bits = 0;
char byte = 1;

while(byte!=0)
{
    bits++;
    byte = byte << 1;
}
```

Each iteration finds about bit in `byte`. When you run out of bits, byte becomes 0.

Using `CHAR_BITS` is better, though.